# Do z-wave products suffer any limitations in the UK because of radio limits?

Tags: electrical, home-automation

I'm looking into home automation and I think I'm settling on z-wave as my choice. however, I was slightly worried by [this comment on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Wave#Radio_specifics);

> In Europe, the 868 MHz band has a 1% duty cycle limitation, thus a Z-Wave unit can only transmit 1% of the time. Z-Wave units can be in power-save mode and only be active 0.1% of the time, thus reducing power consumption substantially.

Does anyone know if this means that z-wave is limited in the UK? For example, does it mean that there are products and applications that are less capable in the UK than in the US, or product which can't be used? Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z-Wave is not limited in UK as Z-Wave is a standard protocol, the Power Save mode CAN be enabled but is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

I would also point out that wikipedia article has got it wrong. It's not 1% but rather 10% It comes under the European Directive "EN 300 220"

Comment: would suggest you fix article..  just like here, users are enpowered

Comment: Im pretty sure normal users can no longer amend Wikipedia articles due to continuous negative alterations. I have read that a few times but I have never tried

Comment: Ahh, could be.  My last edit was several years ago.